# Python pandas: group by two columns, sum on one but not on the others

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, df:

| Location | Category | Species | Number | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | Duiker | P monticola | 3 | 9.1 | -2.1 |
| a | Duiker | C callipygus | 6 | 9.1 | -2.1 |
| b | Duiker | C callipygus | 4 | 9.2 | -2.2 |
| b | Carnivore | G servalina | 2 | 9.2 | -2.2 |
| b | Carnivore | G maculata | 3 | 9.2 | -2.2 |
| c | Carnivore | C aurata | 1 | 9.3 | -2.3 |

I want to convert df into the following format with these conditions:

1. remove the Species column
2. group by Category AND Location
3. in grouping, aggregate Number values
4. but do not aggregate columns x & y
   (same for any Location)

So that df:

| Location | Category | Number | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | Duiker | 9 | 9.1 | -2.1 |
| b | Duiker | 4 | 9.2 | -2.2 |
| b | Carnivore | 5 | 9.2 | -2.2 |
| c | Carnivore | 1 | 9.3 | -2.3 |

My current method would be to:

1. split df into df1 and df2, where

```
df1 = df[['Location', 'Category', 'Number']].copy()
df2 = df[['Location', 'x', 'y']].copy()
```

2. group and sum df1 by Location and Category

```
df1 = df1.groupby('Location', 'Category']).sum()
```

3. Merge intersect df1 and df2 on Location and Category

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'inner', on = ['Location'])
```

Instead on step-3. I get a df3 where the Category column is removed and the Locations are no longer grouped, like this:

| Location | Number | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 9 | 9.1 | -2.1 |
| a | 9 | 9.1 | -2.1 |
| b | 4 | 9.2 | -2.2 |
| b | 4 | 9.2 | -2.2 |
| c | 1 | 9.3 | -2.3 |

I'm a bit lazy and a bit stuck, can someone throw me a bone? and perhaps make my coding more efficient in the process. Thank you in advance.

Comment: A simple approach, is that you can chose the unique location column with your solution.

Comment: you need to drop the duplicates in `df2`

Answer (score 3):

Specify the columns and functions in `agg`:

- `sum` the "Number" column
- keep the `first` values in columns "x" and "y"

```
>>> df.groupby(["Location","Category"],as_index=False).agg({"Number":"sum","x":"first","y":"first"})

  Location   Category  Number    x    y
0        a     Duiker       9  9.1 -2.1
1        b  Carnivore       5  9.2 -2.2
2        b     Duiker       4  9.2 -2.2
3        c  Carnivore       1  9.3 -2.3
```

Comment: I think OP over-complicated the problem. I had the exact same answer ;)

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much! @not_speshal
And, chancellor mozway, over complicating things [is my] speciality ;)